# Short circuiting voltage source

Tags: short-circuit, voltage-source

I was working on a problem for finding the thevinin equivalent circuit. In order to find the short circuit current , I short circuited the terminals across which I had to find the thevinin impedance.

The terminals contain a  dependent voltage source .

My question is does the shot circuit which I have described short circuit the dependent voltage source.

In other words cab we short circuit a dependent voltage source.

Or

Does the dependent voltage source become redundant after a short circuit.

Thank you

Anupam

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irresistible_force_paradox  In other words, you can't do that - the models are invalid in that situation, and if you try to do it with real approximations, the fact that they approximate only in limited conditions will become apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dependent voltage source is across the terminals, you cannot short circuit the terminals to find to short circuit current. The Thevenin equivalent can be found by calculating the open-circuit voltage and the Thevenin resistance.  To find the Thevenin resistance, you zero any independent sources and excite the circuit by applying a current to the terminals and calculating the resulting terminal voltage. The Thevenin resistance is the ratio of voltage to current.